# Table moves every time under last object HTML

Tags: html, html-table

The html table I made always turns under the last object, and I cannot add any other elements because the table always disappears under the last element, in this case an image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And how can we help...? what am I supposed to say? you provided no code, no screenshot, absolutely nothing. How, in your opinion, should one help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry my fault, im new here!

Comment: Why did you put a **screenshot** of the code instead of simply writing it in the question? it's most bizarre.

Comment: I think you are missing a </table> at the end of the table

Comment: Wow, that is some outdated code... Read how to create a [mcve], nobody needs to rewrite this code in order to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two `<tr>` tags below the lines of code for Chris/Nibali and  Tom/Alberto. Also change your last `</tr>` to a `</table>`. You might also have one too many closing `</div>` statements, but it's too hard to tell from your screenshot.